# Modifying V8 JavaScript Engine provided with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, spidermonkey, javascript-engine

I want support for a new API that is normally not supported by V8 JS Engine provided with Chrome. Is it possible to do this by tweaking V8 provided with Chrome.

I'm open to using Spidermonkey which is provided with Firefox. I just want this API to be supported by a popular browser.

I tried looking for an answer on Google forums and here but most of them talk about embedding V8.

Comment: You could modify v8, compile, then try embedding in webkit, which is a close relative to chrome than spidermonkey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a thought...

> For example, a V8 developer may wish to checkout the V8 trunk
>   alongside a stable version of Chromium. So, they might setup a
>   .gclient file like so:
>
> ```
>  solutions = [   
>  { 
>      "name"        : "chrome",
>      "url"         : "http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome@5000",
>      "custom_deps" : {
>        "v8" : "http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk"
>      }   
> }]
> ```

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chromium-modularization

You could perhaps compile Chromium with your own version of v8 by pointing the custom_deps for v8 to it.